# javascript fade / zoom effect .. what am i doing wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the second layer background color to fade (opacity) and scale in the picture div2 .. trying to create something like http://fantasy.co/work

Here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/v2jmy8rh/)

I could not post the whole code as I dont have  enough points... Please follow the link and suggest what should do

The JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".background-color-container").css("opacity", 0.5);
    $(".background-color-container").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/v2jmy8rh/2/ I added jQuery to the fiddle, and `id="imgDemo"`, which was also missing, to the first div.

Comment: You could do this with **CSS transitions** on `hover`, which I think would be simplier.

Comment: @ChrisG yes something like that but i want the red background color to hide the picture and only shown on mouse over by reducing opacity of the background.. and the picture to scale in.

Comment: @TheNagaTanker can you let me know what you mean by "scale in"? like it starts small then goes big? let me know. i think i can help

Comment: okay I have the Issues sorted, however the easing does not seem to work... the updated link https://jsfiddle.net/v2jmy8rh/12/ .... the picture suddenly jumps in and out... if you guys can help me figure it out. I want it to ease it in/out slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this logic in your solution [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/567/)

```css
    div {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background: url('http://pimg.tradeindia.com/00288122/b/0/Our-Valuable-Client-List-Click-on-Image-.jpg');
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        -moz-transition: all .5s;
        -webkit-transition: all .5s;
        transition: all .5s;
        background-position: center center;
    }
    
    div:hover {
        background-size: 150% 150%;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks... got that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly css transition  :

just add the :

```
#imgDemo:hover .div3 img{
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

#imgDemo:hover .div2 img{
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.div3 img {
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
.div2 img {
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

below your worknig example :

```css
.div1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 99;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.div2 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.div3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-container {
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.image-container img {
  width: 125px !important;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 40;
}



.div1:hover .div3 img{
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

.div1:hover .div2 img{
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.div3 img {
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
.div2 img {
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/absolute_vodka_collection_alcohol_drinks_20440_1920x1080.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="https://ez.no/var/ezflow_site/storage/images/media/images/symfony-2.3-lts-in-ez-publish-platform-5.2/390464-1-eng-GB/Symfony-2.3-LTS-in-eZ-Publish-Platform-5.2_fancybox.png" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply. I've managed to solve it... https://jsfiddle.net/v2jmy8rh/17/  its all working as expected... take a look.. any improvements or inputs will be appreciated.